# Can't get my website to run full screen in mobile browsers (when saved to home screen)

Tags: javascript, web-applications, fullscreen, progressive-web-apps

I'm pretty new to javascript, and recently created a website as practice. I've been trying to get the website to display as a fullscreen web app in mobile browsers, but nothing seems to be working.  I've been to basically every relevant website and resource that I can find but still nothing. I'm starting to think that it's probably some stupid small error somewhere else that I've overlooked. Any help from more experienced parties will be very much appreciated<3

Website for reference: [is](http://changeit.netlify.com)

Things I've tried:

1) `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

**result:** didn't seem to make any visible difference to the mobile webapp, and same result when i added to home screen and tried opening from there.

2) creating a complete manifest.json file, linking it to my index.html. Chrome dev tools couldn't detect my manifest file, but pwabuilder.com could.

I've also tried changing the / in the source (linking manifest.json in the index.html) and also tried both attempts above together and separately. I read that it could be a cache issue, so I also tried clearing my cache several times, reinstalling chrome, among many other futile attempts.

this is the relevant part of my index.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 0.7,  user-scalable = no">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

when I try the pwa approach (using a manifest.json) for some reason chrome doesnt detect my manifest file. I've troubleshooted and my code and links are identical to several tutorials and references but it still doesn't detect. I still tried it out on my iphone but it still opens safari from my home screen.

tried the apple meta tag approach as well but that line of code literally doesn't make a visible difference too.

Comment: I think you will need initial scale 1, 0.7 seems odd..

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue with your particular website is that the manifest is not in the header. Below is some example code that shows the correct location for the manifest link.

Also make sure that your manifest contains the minimum elements to be considered eligible for install if you want to have an add to home screen button on Chrome for Android (must have short_name or name, must include a 192px and a 512px sized icons, start_url, display must be one of: fullscreen, standalone, or minimal-ui). You can find more information on the [Google PWA Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) website.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><!-- Note manifest is in the header -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Content Here</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is in the header though:(  I think you should be able to see my full code at the website changeit.netlify.com under source. chrome still isn't detecting my manifest file at all. so frustrating haha

Comment: If I recall, the last time I looked at it (on mobile right now) the head tag was in the body tag which is not correct, they each should be children of the html tag. The site appears down right now so I can't confirm...

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome DevTools you can check manifest.json on the Application menu item, there is a Application / Manifest section.

Comment: yeah I'm aware of that. I mentioned in my post that chrome dev tools isn't detecting my manifest file.

Comment: @tmlyw sorry didn´t realize that

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Problem seemed to be that I had too much going on in my . i just shifted a bunch of HTML into the body section and manifest got detected by chrome dev tools.